# How do I keep objects on same level on minimap?

Tags: unity-game-engine

this is the minimap tutorial I'm using for my minimap:

[Minimap Tutorial](http://blog.theknightsofunity.com/implementing-minimap-unity/)

I have minimap working just like link teaches. There is a problem though. In my game, enemies spawn on different heights. I want to see them on minimap in one level (like any other games where height doesn't matter and shows objects as same size on the minimap). Right now, higher height objects are shown closer and bigger to minimap camera, while lower height objects are shown further and smaller to minimap camera.

Is there way to do this? (as in, same size on minimap regardless of heights)

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just realized I can do this by re-sizing Enemy/PlayerSphere.